# Select Tag Helper with grouping elements

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tag-helpers

Does [Select tag helper](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/views/working-with-forms.html#the-select-tag-helper) in ASP.NET MVC Core have grouping option such as the one shown below. I'm using latest versions of ASP.NET Core and VS2015:

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="Swedish Cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="German Cars">
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

**Display**:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The SELECT tag helper can render opt groups for the options. All you have to do is to provide a `Group` property value when you create a new `SelectListItem` object.

```
var swedish = new SelectListGroup { Name="Swedish" };
var german = new SelectListGroup { Name="German" };

var optionItems = new List<SelectListItem>
{
  new SelectListItem { Value="vovlo", Text = "Volvo", Group = swedish },
  new SelectListItem { Value="saab", Text="Saab", Group = swedish },
  new SelectListItem { Value="mercedes", Text="Mercedes", Group = german } ,
  new SelectListItem { Value="audi", Text ="Audi", Group = german } 
}; 
// use optionItems for asp-items when using SELECT tag helper
```

Answer (score 1):

The select tag helper has an `items` param, where you pass an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. `SelectListItem` has a property, `Group`, which is an instance of `SelectListGroup`. In other words, this is really about how you set up your list of `SelectListItem`s. The tag helper should generate `optgroup`s if you have them defined.